# Searching text file for string in python

Tags: python, function, parsing, wildcard

I'm using Python to search a large text file for a certain string, below the string is the data that I am interested in performing data analysis on.

```
def my_function(filename, variable2, variable3, variable4):
array1 = []

with open(filename) as a:
    special_string = str('info       %d        info =*' %variable3)
    for line in a:
        if special_string == array1:
            array1 = [next(a) for i in range(9)]
            line = next(a)    
            break
        elif special_string != c:
            c = line.strip()
```

In the `special_string` variable, whatever comes after `info =` can vary, so I am trying to put a wildcard operator as seen above. The only way I can get the function to run though is if I put in the exact string I want to search for, including everything after the equals sign as follows:

```
special_string = str('info         %d       info = more_stuff' %variable3)
```

How can I assign a wildcard operator to the rest of the string to make my function more robust?

Comment: Use a regex. `*` does not work in Python string operations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your special string **always** occurs at the start of a line, then you can use the below check (where `special_string` **does not** have the `*` at the end):

```
line.startswith(special_string)
```

Otherwise, please do look at the [module `re` in the standard library](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/re.html) for working with regular expressions.

Comment: This wound up working the best for this situation since it is always at the beginning of the line. To make it more robust though I need to figure out re.

Comment: If you work a lot with strings and regular expressions ... I have heard many good things about that module ... and that page has a lot of good examples to get started with...

Answer (score 1):

Have you thought about using something like this?
Based on your input, I'm assuming the following:

```
variable3 = 100000
special_string = str('info         %d       info = more_stuff' %variable3)

import re
pattern = re.compile('(info\s*\d+\s*info\s=)(.*)')
output = pattern.findall(special_string)
print(output[0][1])
```

Which would return:

```
more_stuff
```